Two reducible polynomials over $\mathbb Q[X]$
I`ve asked it here before, but figured out that there was a minor typo, and as I didnt received any answer I deleted my old question and I am posting again.
I apologize if it is elementary, but here goes.
Let $f$ be a polynomial in $Q[x]$ with integer coefficients define $g = a_n^{n-1}f(a_{n}^{-1}X)$ where $f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots a_1x + a_0$
prove that if there is $p, q  \in Q[x]$ such that $ g = pq$ then there exists $p_1,q_1 \in Q[x]$ such that $ f= p_1q_1$
I think that if g is decomposable, since that $a_n^{n-1}$ is a unit then it means that $f(a_{n}^{-1}X)$ is decomposable, let say $f=p_1q_1$ if we make $a_{n-1}^{-1}X = Y$ then we have $f(y) =p_1(y)q_1(y)$ but I think it is not the right way since that $f(y) \neq f(x)$ are not the same polynomial.
Furthermore, I gotta prove that the degree of $p_1$ and $q_1$ is equal to p and q, respectively. Can someone give me a hint of how to tackle this problem?
Thanks in advance.

I presume you don't count $p_1(X) = 1$, $q_1(X) = f(X)$.  But why not take $p_1(X) = a_n^{1-n} p(a_n X)$ and $q_1(X) = q(a_nX)$?
